# set Jaxb encoding in Mule

Tags: jaxb, mule

I'm running Mule 3.8 CE and my JAXB context and marshaller always create files declared like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

However the files are always UTF-16, and they get marshalled to utf-16,  but the declaration says otherwise and I haven't found a way to solve that. I'm not sure how to set properties on my marshaller in Mule?
Feels a little stupid to have an external script just for replacing that string.

Regards

Comment: `marshaller.setProperty("jaxb.encoding", "UTF-16");` wont work?

Comment: I never have the marshaller Object in code unfortunately, only in mule xml
<mulexml:jaxb-object-to-xml-transformer name="productMarshaller" jaxbContext-ref="JAXB_Context" doc:name="productMarshaller" encoding="UTF-16" mimeType="application/xml"/>